# How to change the background image of the form by clicking on the button?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application there is a menu through which the form opens to change the background image of the form, which also opens through the menu.

[image]

There are 3 background images that are in the local folder, they are selected through these buttons.

[image]

The form "Trenirovka" is not open when the button in the form "Personaji" is clicked

I tried adding this code to the button to select the background:

```
Trenirovka.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\1288957\source\repos\kursovaya\kursovaya\bin\fon_begemotgood.png");
```

but it gives an error, what can i do?

Comment: _"but it gives an error"_ - what's the error?

Comment: Compiler Error CS0120

Comment: You cannot use `Trenirovka` to refer to the Form. If it's the current Form, then use `this` (or just the Property). If it's a different Form than the current, you need the instance of  the opened `Trenirovka` Form. Post some code that describe the context in which the exception is thrown -- BTW, you cannot use a fixed path like that to load an image. Use, e.g., `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "fon_begemotgood.png");`

Answer (score 0):

One approach to achieve this is by using events.

In the `Personaji` form, define an event that will be triggered when a background image is selected:

```cs
public event Action<string> BackgroundImageSelected;

private void SelectBackgroundButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Assuming the image file paths are stored in an array or list
    string selectedImagePath = @"C:\Users\1288957\source\repos\kursovaya\kursovaya\bin\fon_begemotgood.png";

    // Trigger the event with the selected image path
    BackgroundImageSelected?.Invoke(selectedImagePath);
}
```

In the Trenirovka form, subscribe to the BackgroundImageSelected event and update the background image when the event is triggered:

```cs
public void SubscribeToBackgroundImageEvent(Personaji personajiForm)
{
    personajiForm.BackgroundImageSelected += SetBackgroundImage;
}

private void SetBackgroundImage(string imagePath)
{
    try
    {
        // Load the image from the provided file path
        Image backgroundImage = Image.FromFile(imagePath);

        // Set the background image of the form
        BackgroundImage = backgroundImage;
    }
    catch 
    {
        
    }
}
```

In your application's main code or wherever you create and show the forms, you need to establish the subscription between the forms:

```cs
Trenirovka trenirovkaForm = new Trenirovka();
Personaji personajiForm = new Personaji();
trenirovkaForm.SubscribeToBackgroundImageEvent(personajiForm);

// Show the forms
personajiForm.Show();
trenirovkaForm.Show();
```